# File compiles ok in IntelliJ plugin but does not compile with kotlinc command-line compiler

Tags: kotlin

The following Kotlin source file compiles and runs perfectly using the Kotlin 1.3.11 plugin in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1. However, it fails to compile in the Kotlin command line compiler, giving the following message. Is there something wrong with the code or am I missing a classpath dependency or something?

```
C:\tmp>type Main.kt
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths

fun main() {
    Files.lines(Paths.get("t.txt"))
            .use { lines -> lines.forEach { println(it) } }
}

C:\tmp>kotlinc -version
info: kotlinc-jvm 1.3.11 (JRE 1.8.0_192-b12)

C:\tmp>kotlinc Main.kt
Main.kt:6:14: error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
@InlineOnly public inline fun <T : Closeable?, R> ???.use(block: (???) -> ???): ??? defined in kotlin.io
            .use { lines -> lines.forEach { println(it) } }
             ^
Main.kt:6:20: error: cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
            .use { lines -> lines.forEach { println(it) } }
                   ^
Main.kt:6:35: error: cannot choose among the following candidates without completing type inference:
@HidesMembers public inline fun <T> Iterable<???>.forEach(action: (???) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
@HidesMembers public inline fun <K, V> Map<out ???, ???>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<???, ???>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
            .use { lines -> lines.forEach { println(it) } }
                                  ^
Main.kt:6:53: error: unresolved reference: it
            .use { lines -> lines.forEach { println(it) } }
                                                    ^

C:\tmp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

The `use` function is not defined in `kotlin-stdlib` but in `kotlin-std-jdk7` (see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/use.html)

**Solution**

```
kotlinc -classpath kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.11.jar Main.kt
```